# Akka Camel with Jetty throws NoSuchMethodError: UnsafeUriCharactersEncoder

Tags: java, jetty, apache-camel, akka

I'm trying to run a simple Akka-Camel consumer. I created a server which replies to the address in the uri (in the code example). When I run the code, I get an exception.
I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong, do I need to configure Jetty somehow? If so, how?

This Akka sample i'm using as an example and in their example the uri is written in simple string.
(https://github.com/akka/akka/tree/master/akka-samples/akka-sample-camel-java)

**Exception:**

```
Uncaught error from thread [test-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] shutting down     JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[test-system]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.camel.util.UnsafeUriCharactersEncoder.encodeHttpURI(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.JettyHttpComponent.createEndpoint(JettyHttpComponent.java:169)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:91)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:461)
at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:50)
at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.resolveEndpoint(RouteDefinition.java:186)
...
...
```

**My code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("test-system");
    ActorRef historyActor = system.actorOf(Props.create(CamelActor.class));
}


public class CamelActor extends UntypedConsumerActor {
    private String uri;
    public CamelActor() { this.uri = "jetty:http://0.0.0.0:9000/mymain?myparam=true"; }

    @Override
    public String getEndpointUri() { return uri; }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        if (message instanceof CamelMessage) {
            CamelMessage camelMessage = (CamelMessage) message;
            System.out.println("==>"+camelMessage.toString());
        } else {
            unhandled(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Guy

Comment: Looks like you failed to provide all the necessary jar files on the classpath _at runtime_.

Comment: You are correct, I indeed forgot the Camel Core.

Comment: Please add an answer and mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this is caused by multiple camel, servlet-api, jetty versions being used in project's dependencies. Removing the duplicates apis solved the issue. Remove all duplicate dependencies from the build path.